# How to prevent printing out a message when ZeroDivisionError occurs?

Tags: python, calculator

How do I prevent Python from printing out the division equation in another function when `ZeroDivisionError` occurs even after handling the error in a different function?

```py
def divide(x, y):

    try:
        return x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("\nMath ERROR - Division by 0")


def calculate(num_1, num_2):

    choice = select_choice()

    if choice == 1:
        print("\n", num_1, "+", num_2, "=", add(num_1, num_2))
    elif choice == 2:
        print("\n", num_1, "-", num_2, "=", subtract(num_1, num_2))
    elif choice == 3:
        print("\n", num_1, "*", num_2, "=", multiply(num_1, num_2))
    elif choice == 4:
        print("\n", num_1, "/", num_2, "=", divide(num_1, num_2))
    elif choice == 5:
        print("\n", num_1, "^", num_2, "=", exponentiate(num_1, num_2))
```

This is my current code and in the `divide` function, I've put a `try` `except` blocks to handle 0 division error. But inside `calculate` function, `elif choice == 4:` will still print out the equation.

Comment: with Python Exception Handling – ZeroDivisionError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go inside the `except` block in the `divide` method, it'll then return a `None` value (default return value), you can use that in the `calculate` method to determine whether or not to display the equation and result

```
elif choice == 4:
    result = divide(num_1, num_2)
    if result:
        print("\n", num_1, "/", num_2, "=", result)
```

Comment: Ohhh this one works! But, may I know how did `if result:` managed to know that `ZeroDivisionError` did not occur? Is it because if the returned value is 1 and not 0, it returns true, hence `if result:`? Also, I tried putting the `try...except` statements inside the `calculate` function and it works the same. But I'm not sure if doing that is correct.

This is what I did:

```
    elif choice == 4:
        try:
            print("\n", num_1, "/", num_2, "=", divide(num_1, num_2))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("\nMath ERROR - Division by 0")
```

Comment: @RoyalFrog As i said, if you don't use the `return x/y` (meaning Exception), it'll `return None` (default behaviour), s the if check is like `if result is not None` but `if result` does same